# ComboPooledDataSource poolsize configurations not working

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm using `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` as my datasource for an **Oracle DB** in a `Spring MVC` web project.

Here's my bean properties configurations for this class:

```
<bean id="pmiDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:port/SID" />
        <property name="user" value="****" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value ="10" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15" />
</bean>
```

here, no matter how I set the pool size, it doesn't change the threads number of `ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner`.
e.g

1.

```
<property name="minPoolSize" value ="1" />
<property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="15" />
```

2.

```
<property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
<property name="initialPoolSize" value ="6" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="15" />
```

I always have 3 thread in my JVisual VM

[image: Threads in the JVM]

**UPDATE** : help help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config parameter you are looking for is [numHelperThreads](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#numHelperThreads).

Comment: Oh yes it works. By the way, does this thread has anything to do with the maximum number of hibernate session?

Comment: no, this is a c3p0-level setting, the number of helper threads (pooled threads) per c3p0 DataSource. it doesn't know anything about hibernate.